# How to access values of previous page at client-side?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a page and clicked on the button there it will open a new page containing some text boxes, user fill all the text boxes and clicked the button now first page open again and the question is : How can I get the vales of text boxes on the current page using both server-side and client-side

There is a restrictions to use of : 
- Cross-paging
- Cookies
- Sessions
- Query strings

Comment: There is an example here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/QueryString.aspx and here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Request/SendandgetquerystringC.htm

Comment: @Gaurav:this is the only way: abswrite(0,0,0,0,"My text here");  string mystring = absread(0,0,0,0);

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand.  You're not allowed to use any of `Cross-paging - Cookies - Sessions - Query strings`  In order to transfer data between pages, you have to have some sort of persistence. The only other options you have are Application state, POST, Cache and Context, but it sounds like you don't want any of these.  The list of persistence choices is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx

Comment: Sorry mate,
Choices are not in my hands actually this is what my client needs?

Comment: Your client has nonsensical needs then. Why are those techniques a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Server-side approach:**

An alternate approach is to use `Server.Transfer` method.

On the current page:

```
protected void Transfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Page.IsValid)
  {
    Server.Transfer("destination.aspx");
  }
}
```

On the destination page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (PreviousPage != null)
  {
    TextBox textBox = PreviousPage.FindControl("Parameter")
                        as TextBox;
 
    if (textBox != null)
    {
      string parameter = textBox.Text;
      Parameter.Text = parameter;
    }
 
  }   
}
```

But `Server.Transfer` does come with disadvantages. The most serious is that the URL in the browser does not change. The browser still believes it has posted back and received content for the first web form, so history and book-marking suffer.

**Client-side approach:**

In real world I don't recommend to use this solution, this is only a workaround.

In two words: use `window.name` property on the client side. This property is available across page reloads it is a sort of session.

For more information see:

- [What’s in a window.name?](http://ajaxian.com/archives/whats-in-a-windowname)
- [window.name Transport](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/22/windowname-transport/)

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the PostBackUrl property of the button on the submitting page, you can access the controls for the "previous page" from the action page by using the following:

```
Dim txtBox as TextBox
txtBox = CType(Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("MyTextBox"), TextBox)
```

Then you'll have access programmatically to all of the properties and data for that control.

Comment: There is restriction to use Cross-paging

Comment: He can't use any of `Cross-paging - Cookies - Sessions - Query strings`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `cache` if you can't use the `Session`, `Querystring`, `Cookies` and Cross Page posting.

Answer (score 0):

If it is simple/primitive data, then you can go for the `ViewState`. Or `Cache` is a better option.
One more option is to have a Page level public variables, set the required values and redirect to the page for further processing.(This is not a good approach to follow)